# @NgCallback with parameters using RootContext

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Using the traditional way from Controller causes :

```
type 'RootContext' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of '_scope@0xXXXXXXXXX'
```

And thats normal due to the difference between @Controller and RootContext

Since RootContext is now available, how can i use it with @NgCallback with parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a temporary limitation of RootContext since RootContext doesn't yet extends Map

See [similar issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1416)